# Wagtail admin icons disappear when running collectstatic and putting everything on S3

Tags: django, python-3.x, amazon-s3, wagtail

I've been working locally and on my server and everything looks good. Then I configure django-storages to store static files and media on my S3 bucket. Everything works except for the icons/glyphicons on the admin interface. Instead of the nice pretty graphic icons, I see letters.

For example once you log in, you have the search bar on the left side. Normally you would see a looking glass in the search box. I lost the looking glass and now I just see a lowercase f.

My question is this. What do I search for to start debugging this? What wagtail file is `collectstatic` not collecting?

#### Steps to Reproduce

1. Set up a wagtail site
2. Set up a bucket on s3
3. Install django-storages
4. Configure django-storages to use your bucket
5. `./manage.py collectstatic`

#### Technical details

- Python version: 3.5.2
- Django version: 1.11.5
- Wagtail version: 1.12.2
- Browser version: firefox, chromium, chrome

[image: selection_031]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This happens because Wagtail uses an icon font, and current browsers don't allow loading fonts from remote domains unless they include valid CORS HTTP headers. You can configure the django-storages S3 backend to add the appropriate headers by adding the following lines to your settings file:

```
AWS_HEADERS = {
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
}
```

and re-running `./manage.py collectstatic`. See https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/issues/633#issuecomment-55935529 for some additional notes.

Comment: It's been a while, but yes this was the answer. Apologies for the delay.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this issue too. Since v1.9 of django-storages, it has used [boto3 instead of boto](https://django-storages.readthedocs.io/en/latest/backends/amazon-S3.html). The "AWS_HEADERS" fix by gasman does not work for boto3. However, setting these CORS rules in Amazon S3, which I found [here](https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/issues/633), resolved the issue for me:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
    <AllowedHeader>Authorization</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

As mentioned in the linked github response, it's probably best to update

```
<AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
```

to

```
<AllowedOrigin>http://www.example.com</AllowedOrigin>
```

Here is the [Amazon documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cors.html) for CORS settings.

Comment: Do you need to re-collectstatic after doing this change?

Comment: I don't recall, but I expect I did because I do that regularly.

Comment: @michela No you do not have to. Just tested it on my site.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using wagtail==2.10.1 and django==3.1.1 and using Digital Ocean Spaces (DO version of AWS s3). I ran into this same problem but solutions did not work (it has been two years since this was posted after all...). I realized this was beacuse since the solution was posted, django-storages and boto3 have updated. The format for their config settings have changed.

So if you are using boto3 dependency with django-storage on wagtail, you can replace this solution from @gasman:

```
AWS_HEADERS = {
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
}
```

with this updated code:

```
AWS_S3_OBJECT_PARAMETERS = {
        'ACL':'public-read',
}
```

I understand that there may be security issues with having `public-read`, but this is what got it working for me.

Answer (score 0):

I used *wagtail==2.5.1* and *django==2.2.1* static get from aws s3. 
And the issue was in credentials to boto s3. When I updated credentials and make `manage.py collectstatic` all static loaded and site work well))